# fstat Returning 0 File Size

Tags: c, fstat

I thought I understood fstat, I was wrong.

I need to know the size of the file then read from the file.

`fileN`  Has the path of the file and the name of the file. It looks like this. 0.txt

```
struct stat fileStat;

FILE *fp;
int fd = 0; 


int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   fp = fopen(fileN, "r");

   fd = open(fileN, "r"); // I think this is eating my files and making them 0 size.
   fstat(fd, $fileStat);

   printf("%d", fileStat.st_size);

   fclose(fp);
}
```

Why do I need to use `fd = open(fileN, "r");` To use fstat? It feels like I am opening the file twice.

If fileStat is a struct why do I use `fileStat.st_size` instead of `fileStat->st_size` like I do when I create my own structs? Example: `myString->characters`;

And why is the code above printing 0s when `printf` is executed? And yes the files have a size bigger than 0 and I have the correct file name and path.

*All code above is my interpretation of code that was Googled and mixed with my trial and error implementation. That's why I have so many questions.*

EDIT: **SOLUTION**: open() was being called wrong and affecting the files.

Comment: You need to check the return value of fopen, open and fstat. Also, open() is not called properly.

Comment: How would you check the return value of fopen. if(fp == NULL) return -1;?

Comment: That would be one way. Often a printf is used to say that the fopen failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Why do I need to use fd = open(fileN, "r"); To use fstat? It feels like I am opening the file twice.

Because `fstat()` requires a file descriptor. You could use `stat()` instead, which takes a filename. Or you could use `fd = fileno(fp)` to get the file descriptor from the stdio `FILE`.

BTW, you need to call `close(fd)` in the loop.

- If fileStat is a struct why do I use fileStat.st_size instead of fileStat->st_size like I do when I create my own structs? Example: myString->characters;

You use `->` when the variable on the left is a pointer to a struct, you use `.` when it's the struct itself. This is basic C syntax, nothing specific to `fstat`.

- And why is the code above printing 0s when printf is executed? And yes the files have a size bigger than 0 and I have the correct file name and path.

You're not calling `open()` correctly. The second argument is supposed to be an `int` containing flags. Since you give a string instead, the pointer to the string is being coerced to an int, and the bits in this are probably not valid open flags. You need to check the return value of `open` to see if it succeeded -- it will return `-1` if there's an error. Similarly with `fstat` -- it's probably returning an error because `fd` is not valid.

Comment: I set fileN somewhere else, trust me I am printing it and it has the correct path and file name. Removing this stops the deleting of the data inside the file: fd = open(fileN, "r");

Comment: @MikeJohn, heed his advice and check the return values.

Comment: Yes, open() was being called incorrectly. I instead used fileno(fp).